# How can the color of the done button of MPMoviePlayerViewController be changed

Tags: colors, ios6, mpmovieplayercontroller

How can the color of the done button of MPMoviePlayerViewController be changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution:

```
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:161.0/255.0 green: 52.0/255.0 blue: 238.0/255.0 alpha: 1.0]];
```